# Router param always return undefined in activate method

Tags: javascript, aurelia

i've created below router which is suppose to have a optional parameter called `name`. however when i for instance access `dashboard/test` it returnes `{'name': undefined}`. I have no idea on why it returns `undefined`, since i'm accessing the params in the activate method.

**router**

```
export class App {

    configureRouter(config, router) {
        //config.options.pushState = true;
        config.title = 'Aurelia';
        config.addAuthorizeStep(AuthorizeStep);
        config.options.root = '/';
        config.map([
        {
            route: 'dashboard/:name?',
            name: 'dashboard',
            moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('components/dashboard/dashboardcomponent'),
            title: 'Dashboard',
            layoutView: PLATFORM.moduleName('shared/layouts/app-layout.html'),
            nav: true,
            href: '#',
            settings: {
            auth: true
            }
        }
        ]);

        this.router = router;

    }
}
```

**dashboardcomponent**

```
@inject(DashboardService, Store, Router)
export class DashboardComponent {

    routeParam = null;

    // Booleans
    isLoading = false;
    hasDashboards = false;

    // dashboard docs
    dashboards = [];

    //selected dashboard
    dashboard = {};

    constructor(dashboardservice, store, router) {
        this.dashboardservice = dashboardservice;
        this.store = store;
        this.router = router;
    }


    activate(params, routeConfig) {
        console.log(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `config` in `config.map(...)` an array?

Comment: I created this as a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aurelia-router-demo-km1gr?fontsize=14&initialpath=%23%2Fdashboard%2Ftest) and it works fine. make sure you are not running an old cache version of your code.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you didn't notice the comment, so I'm posting this as an answer.

I created this as a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aurelia-router-demo-km1gr?fontsize=14&initialpath=%23%2Fdashboard%2Ftest) and it works fine.

it's not exactly the same.. because you didn't post all the relevant code.

1. make sure you are not running an old cache version of your code.
2. make sure you are not tempering the data in your `AuthorizeStep`